# Style appliance in combobox

Tags: wpf

I have simple window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Content="1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="2"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="3"/>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

But this style is not applyed to combobox. If I move it to app.xaml it starts works.
Could someone to explain this strange behaviour?

Comment: Strange, but your targettype is TextBlock. It should be ComboBox. But why it works when you put it in app.xaml is a mystery to me. I would expect it not to work there either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The styles in `App.xaml` are applied inside templates, this means that if the ComboBoxItem internally creates a TextBlock that only is affected by those global styles.

To change text colours you should set `Foreground` or [`TextElement.Foreground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.foreground.aspx) on the ComboBox itself (for which you can also use a style).

Comment: Yes, it explains. Could you provide links that explains this behaviors more details?

Comment: Controls inside templates are not in the logical tree which is used in one stage of the resource lookup, but the lookup directly checks the application resources, possibly [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx#staticdynamic) can explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
    <Window.Resources>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="TextStyle">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextStyle}">            
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```